# Probabilities of uncountable intersection of events

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

In order to determine a probability for some event $A\in\Omega$, I ended up with

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_t>f(t),\quad \forall [0,T]\right)≤ \mathbb{P}(A)≤\mathbb{P}\left(X_t≥f(t),\quad \forall [0,T]\right),
$$

where $X_t$ is a continuous stochastic process$^*$ and $f(t)$ is a deterministic continuous function, both real-valued.

The Question is whether $$\mathbb{P}\left(X_t>f(t),\ \forall [0,T]\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_t≥f(t),\ \forall [0,T]\right)\tag{1}$$ true or not?

For finite intersections it's definitely true, i.e. $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{t_1}>f(t_1),X_{t_2}>f(t_2)\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{t_1}≥f(t_1),X_{t_2}≥f(t_2)\right)$. The same is (perhaps) valid for countable intersections. Is it possible to show, that this is also true for uncountable case (1)?

Thank you for your contribution.

$^*\textbf{Edit:}$ Let's assume that $X_t$ is Brownian motion or geometric Brownian motion. In general it is obvious not true. Thanks to David Giraudo and Did.

Comment: You can deduce the countable case from the finite one using $\mu(A_n)\to \mu(A)$ if $A_n\downarrow A$. Then write $\bigcap_{t\in [0,1]}\{X_t\geqslant 0\}=\bigcap_{t\in [0,1]\cap\mathbb Q}\{X_t\geqslant 0\}$.

Comment: Thank you Davide. You are right. With $\bigcap_{t\in[0,1]}\{X_t≥ 0\}=\bigcap_{t\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{X_t≥ 0\}$ you can show for the right hand side of (1) that $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{t\in[0,1]}\{X_t≥ 0\}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{t\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{X_t≥ 0\}\right)$. In order to prove the validity of (1) it would be enough to show that $\bigcap_{t\in[0,1]}\{X_t> 0\}=\bigcap_{t\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{X_t> 0\}$ is also true. But I have my difficulties exactly at this step, e.g. the function $f(x)=|x-\sqrt{1/2}|$.

Comment: Forgive me  my question, do you mean $\bigcap_{t\in[0,T]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{X_t>0\}\subset \bigcap_{t\in[0,T]}\{X_t>0\}$?

Comment: If we take $X_t:=X$ and $f=0$, the LHS is $P(X>0)$ and the RHS $P(X\geq 0)$, hence if $P(X=0)\neq 0$ it won't work. What do you know about the process $X_t$?

Comment: Let's assume $X_t$ is Brownian motion or geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: In this case, you could be interested by http://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/supremum-of-brownian-motion/.

Answer (score 1):

Not always: consider $X_t=(t-U)^2$ where $U$ is some positive continuous random variable, and $f(t)=0$ for every $t$. Then, for every $T$,
$$
P[\forall t\in[0,T],X_t\gt f(t)]=P[U\gt T],
$$
while
$$
P[\forall t\in[0,T],X_t\geqslant f(t)]=1.
$$
Note that, for every $t$, $X_t$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: It was a bit naive of me to formulate the question for general continuous processes, if I already knew, that e.g. for the function $f(x)=|x-\sqrt{1/2}|$ it's not true. You smart example of process $X_t$ confirmed it also.  What's about $X_t:=$ Brownian motion?